# How to get a point that is larger than 1 pixel (radius)

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, cgpoint

I am trying to detect the collision from two objects.  This collision
has more than one option so I would like to know if there is any way
to declare a radius `CGPoint` or something similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a simple way to test if a point is in a circle:

```
-(bool)pointInCircle_circleCenter:(CGPoint)circleCenter circleRadius:(float)radius testPoint:(CGPoint)point{
    float distance = (circleCenter.x-point.x) * 2 + (circleCenter.y-point.y) * 2;
    return distance <= radius * 2;
}
```